# Can you use Apple’s Metal for General Purpose GPU programming?

Tags: gpgpu, metal

I have experience with CUDA, but I’ve been wondering if it’s possible to use Metal as an alternative to OpenCL on a Mac for High Performance Computing purposes. It doesn’t seem like there is a lot of material available of parallel programming with Metal outside of graphics.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use Metal for general purpose GPU programming. Apple provides [some sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/basic_tasks_and_concepts/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu) with a bit of a tutorial.

The main thing that Metal lacks (so far) for compute shaders is support for `double`.